# Como converter TIMESTAMP/DATETIME em GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java

Como faço para converter um **`TIMESTAMP`** ou **`DATETIME`** do MySQL em um `GregorianCalendar` do Java? Ou uma ideia melhor?

Na classe, o campo `dataCadastro` é do tipo `GregorianCalendar`. Estou gravando no banco no tipo **`TIMESTAMP`**`dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00`.

Agora quero fazer o contrário, pegar do banco e gerar o `GregorianCalendar` para compor o objeto.

A ideia é manter os dados completos da data de cadastro do usuário!

Como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

```
Timestamp ts = seuTimeStamp;
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(ts);
```

ou, se for o Date

```
Date d = seuDate;
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(d);
```

Comment: GregorianCalendar. Não Calendar!

Como faz?

Comment: da mesma forma... só que ao inves de usar o getInstance.. você faz um new GregorianCalendar( )